# Test suite failed to run in WebStorm for CRA

Tags: webstorm, jestjs, create-react-app

When I run my CRA and use the run test arrows in WebStorm 2018.2 I get:

> Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/es7.string.pad-start' from
>   'TestUtils.jsx'

Has anyone have come across this one? How to solve?

Comment: please see https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2215, looks like a problem with missing/conflicting babel dependencies. see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13018

Comment: Strange because when I run npm test from the terminal there are no issues?

Comment: must be specific to a way you start you tests in both cases

Comment: Does webstorm not use a jest command for the debug functionality?

Comment: in CRA projects, it runs `react-scripts test`

Comment: Which calls jest

Comment: yes, of course:)